# Issues updating pip

Tags: python, pip

Using `pip` to install various packages I need, I get the following message in yellow text (in the terminal):

```
You are using pip version 7.0.3, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Doing exactly that, i.e. `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`, I get in return

```
Requirement already up-to-date: 
pip in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/
Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

This obviously isn't a huge error (or really anything to worry about too much), but what exactly is going on here?

Comment: What do you see when you run `which pip`?

Comment: `sudo pip` and `pip` are probably two different versions of pip.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I see `/opt/local/bin/pip`

Comment: @cel It doesn't seem like it.